# Bootstrapping for rlmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, bootstrap, robust

I am using the `robustlmm` package and the `rlmer` function to calculate robust estimates for my multi-level data (2-levels and 3-levels). Now I am interested in bootstrapped confidence intervals and std. errors. Sadly the `bootMer` function is not yet implemented in `robustlmm` and I am struggling to find any information on how other people proceeded in that case. Has anyone ever dealt with this problem and may have some advice for me? Thank you!

Comment: You might get better response on the R mailing list for mixed models.